# Make divs scrollable when on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have created a filter layout with html and css.

I am using bootstrap as my basis, but I have heavily customized the template.

Please find below my example:

```css
a:hover {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

article {
  padding-left: 33px;
  padding-right: 33px;
}


/* FACETS */

.extra_callout {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.facetwp-slider-wrap {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.facetwp-counts {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.sort_title,
.facetwp-sort {
  float: left;
}

.facetwp-sort {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#facet_selection {
  float: left;
  width: 216px;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #f3f3f4;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #949599;
}

.facetwp-dropdown {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.facetwp-template #comparison_chart {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.facetwp-template #comparison_chart .tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
}

#facet_selection p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.facetwp-facet {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

#facet_selection .title {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.page-template-page-facet article {
  padding-top: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.page-template-page-facet {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.page-template-page-facet .entry-content {
  float: left;
  width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.facetwp-type-checkboxes,
.facetwp-type-hierarchy {
  max-height: 5000px !important;
}

.cross_buttons {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.page-template-page-facet #sidebar,
.page-template-page-facet .site-content {
  width: 1200px;
}

.page-template-page-experts .site-content {
  width: 950px;
}

.comments-area {
  clear: both;
}

#comparison_chart img {
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faceted .model {
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 50% !important
}

.faceted .tr {
  overflow: auto;
}

.faceted .tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f3f3f4;
}

.additional_link {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ff7f00;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fa5), to(#ff7f00));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  border: 1px solid #bb5d00;
  color: #fff;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffaa55, endColorstr=#ff7f00);
  padding: 8px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  /* Older browser do not support empty content */
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.facetwp-checkbox {
  clear: both;
}

.recommended {
  font-size: 11px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
  color: green;
}

.facetwp-facet-must_have .recommended {
  top: -5px;
  left: 20px;
}

.faceted li.con i {
  color: red !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.faceted .making li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.faceted .making ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-indent: -6px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.faceted .making ul i {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.faceted .model .title {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.entry-content .model a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.faceted .price {
  width: 35% !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.faceted .making {
  width: 50% !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 13.5px;
}

.faceted .pros {
  width: 48% !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-size: 13.5px;
}

.faceted .pros ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.faceted .pros ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.faceted .pros ul li span {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.faceted .pro_con {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -8px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.faceted .pro_con.pro {
  text-indent: -9px;
}

.faceted .container div:last-of-type .comma {
  display: none;
}

.faceted .container div {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.faceted .fa-check {
  color: green;
}

.faceted .fa-times {
  color: red;
}

.faceted .tr {
  clear: both;
}

.faceted .tr>span {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.faceted .header_chart {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.facetwp-sort {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.faceted .add_tooltip {
  top: 145px;
}

.faceted .header_chart .making,
.faceted .header_chart .pros {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.faceted .header_chart .tr>span {
  background: #949599;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 26.9471988677979px;
  text-align: center;
}

.faceted .header_chart .pros {
  font-style: normal;
}

.faceted .header_chart .tr>span:nth-child(even) {
  background: #bdbec1;
}

.faceted .tool {
  width: 100% !important;
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
  top: 20px;
  display: none;
  background: gray;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5000;
  display: none;
}

.site {
  max-width: none;
}

.page-template-page-facet .site-content {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.facet-container #facet_selection {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  width: 74%;
  /*width: 960px;*/
}

.page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.facet-container .faceted .tr>span>span:first-child {
  display: none;
}


/*! Tablet --------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /*#top-container{width:100%;margin:0;}
    #top-container .container{padding:0 .5%;}*/
  .page-template-page-facet .site-content,
  .page-template-page-facet .sidebar {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content,
  .facet-container .entry-content {
    width: 74%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content .model .one_half {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/*! Tablet Portrait--------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (orientation: portrait) {}


/*! Small Tablet --------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {}


/* 480px iphone landscape */

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .page-template-page-facet .site-content,
  .page-template-page-facet .sidebar {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  #masthead {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-web {
    display: none;
  }
  .facet-container #facet_selection {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 2% 0;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
  }
  .facet-container #facet_selection p,
  .facet-container #facet_selection div {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content,
  .facet-container .entry-content {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  .facet-container .entry-content .header_chart {
    display: none;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .tr>span {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    float: none;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .tr>span>span:first-child {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #949599;
    line-height: 26.9472px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center !important;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .price {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .button {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .making ul {
    margin-left: 22px;
  }
}


/* 320px iphone portrait */

@media screen and (max-width: 459px) {}

.cross_buttons {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.buy_link,
.additional_link {
  position: relative;
}

.buy_link {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px;
}

.button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top: medium none;
  border-right: medium none;
  border-left: medium none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  border-image: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: medium none !important;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

.button-rezesionen {
  background: #222 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  ;
}

.button-buy {
  background: #0274BE none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  ;
}

.extra_callout {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.faceted .making ul {
  text-indent: -6px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.faceted ul {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: outside none disc;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin: 0px 0px 1.6em 1.3333em;
}

.faceted .model .title {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.model span {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #666;
}

.price {
  border-bottom: medium none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.faceted .tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #F3F3F4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

.faceted .tr {
  clear: both;
}

.faceted .tr {
  overflow: auto;
}

.facetwp-template #comparison_chart .tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #A9A9A9;
}

.faceted .tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #F3F3F4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

.faceted .tr {
  clear: both;
}

.faceted .tr {
  overflow: auto;
}

.one_half {
  width: 50%;
}

.full_width,
.one_half,
.one_third,
.two_third,
.one_fourth,
.three_fourth,
.one_fifth,
.two_fifth,
.three_fifth,
.four_fifth,
.one_sixth,
.five_sixth {
  float: left;
}

.model span {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #666;
}

#comparison_chart .row.buy,
.faceted .price {
  border-bottom: medium none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#comparison_chart .col .row span {
  display: block;
}

.page-template-page-comparison-new .color-block {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.page-template-page-comparison-new .tab_group.one_fourth {
  width: 20%;
}

#comparison_chart tbody tr {
  display: none;
}

tr.compare_show {
  display: table-row !important;
}

#comparison_chart.compared .key.one_fourth {
  display: block;
}

.page-template-page-comparison-new .sort {
  display: none;
}

.page-template-page-comparison-new .entry-header,
.entry-content {
  padding: 0;
}

.page-template-page-comparison-new .hentry,
.page-template-page-comparison-new .page-header,
.page-content {
  box-shadow: none;
  padding-top: 0;
}


/* style tabs */

#tabs_compare li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#tabs_compare {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  clear: both;
}

#tabs_compare input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#tabs_compare h5 {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

#tabs_compare a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

#tabs_compare a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab_group {
  clear: both;
}

#checkboxes_shown .tab_group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab_group.one_fourth {
  clear: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.tab_group li {
  background: #bdbec1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.tab_group.active li {
  background: #949599;
}

.checkbox_full {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

#checkboxes_shown .tab_group {
  display: none;
}

#checkboxes_shown .tab_group.active {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.Vitamix5200 td {
  background: #D0E9C6 !important;
}

#checkboxes_shown {
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}


/* style results table*/

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #f3f3f4;
}

th {
  background: #949599;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#comparison_chart {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

tr th:nth-child(even) {
  background: #bdbec1;
}

td,
th,
tbody,
tale,
#comparison_chart {
  border: none;
  border-width: 0px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#comparison_chart tr {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc !important;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.containers span,
.controls span {
  display: block;
}

.faceted ul {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#comparison_chart .row.buy a,
.faceted .price a,
.faceted model a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ff7f00;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fa5), to(#ff7f00));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fa5, #ff7f00);
  border: 1px solid #bb5d00;
  color: #fff;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffaa55, endColorstr=#ff7f00);
  padding: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.color-block {
  clear: both;
}

.colors span {
  float: left;
}

.row.buy {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#comparison_chart .labels {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#comparison_chart img {
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#comparison_chart .col .row:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.model span {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #666666;
}

.model {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.price {
  width: 5%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.price a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.buy {
  width: 11% !important;
}

.warranty {
  width: 8% !important;
}

.containers {
  width: 8% !important;
}

.hp {
  width: 5% !important;
}

.making {
  width: 28% !important;
}

.watts {
  width: 7% !important;
}

.accessories {
  width: 12% !important;
  text-align: left;
}

.dimensions {
  width: 12% !important;
  text-align: left;
}

.pros {
  width: auto !important;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

th {
  padding: 5px 4px;
}

th.accessories,
th.dimensions,
th.pros,
th.making {
  text-align: center !important;
}

#comparison_chart .col {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  clear: both;
}

#comparison_chart #column_labels th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.model {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.model img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#comparison_chart .blender .accessories,
#comparison_chart .blender .dimensions,
#comparison_chart .blender .pros,
#comparison_chart .making {
  text-align: left;
}

.col {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 165px !important;
}

#column_labels .col {
  height: auto !important;
}

#Vitamix5200 .col {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}

.blender {
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.buy {
  position: relative;
}

.buy .additional_savings {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.buy a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 15px !important;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.buy_link {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.buy_link,
.additional_link {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip_icon img {
  border: none !important;
}

.tooltip_icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  width: 12px;
}

.buy .tool {
  background: gray;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5000;
  display: none;
  width: 93%;
}

#select_all {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.gform_body {
  z-index: 5000;
  position: relative;
}

.home .gform_footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -75px;
  margin-bottom: -100px !important;
  z-index: 5;
}

.gform_body .one_fourth {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.gform_body .tooltip_icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 15px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: 5000;
  display: none;
}

#compare_choice .one_half {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 49%;
}

#compare_choice .one_half.model {
  margin-right: 1% !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#compare_choice a {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*hide by feature unless someone completed the quiz */

.page-id-22 #gform_wrapper_1 {
  display: none;
}

#gform_wrapper_1 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.widget {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.site-content {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3em !important;
  clear: both;
}

.hentry,
.page-header,
.page-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.facetwp-template #comparison_chart .tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
}

.faceted .tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #F3F3F4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

.faceted .tr {
  clear: both;
}

.faceted .tr {
  overflow: auto;
}

#comparison_chart {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
}

.entry-content,
.entry-summary,
.page-content,
.comment-content {
  hyphens: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.buttonBuy {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffcc00 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top: medium none;
  border-right: medium none;
  border-left: medium none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  border-image: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: medium none !important;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

#facet_selection {
  float: left;
  width: 216px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #F3F3F4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #949599;
}

.faceted li.con i {
  color: #F00 !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.faceted .fa-times {
  color: #F00;
}

.entry-content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#facet_selection {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.entry-content2 {
  float: right;
  width: 795px;
}

#facet_selection {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="main-side page clearfix full_width">
  <article class="post" id="page-1144">
    <div class="entry-content2">
      <div class="facetwp-template" data-name="beistellbetten">
        <div id="comparison_chart" class="faceted">
          <div class="header_chart">
            <div class="tr">
              <span class="model">Modell</span>
              <!--<span class="price">Preis</span>-->
              <span class="making">Recommended</span>
              <!--<span class="pros">Pros/Cons</span>-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tr"><span class="model"><a target="_blank"  href=""><span class="title">Product 1</span>
            <span class="one_half"><img width="300" height="300" src="" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="" srcset=""
                sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"></span><span class="one_half last_column clearfix"><span class="price">179.90 €</span></span>
            </a>
            <span class="cross_buttons">
   <a target="_blank" href="" ><div class="button button-rezesionen buy_link">Link 1</div></a>
   <span class="extra_callout"></span>
            </span>
            </span>
            <span class="making">
        <ul>
            <li class="cleanup"><b>Attribute 1:</b>
                <span class="pro_con"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>DLorem ipsum dolor sum</span> </li>
            <li class="cleanup"><b>Attribute 2:</b>
              <span class="pro_con"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sum</span> </li>
            </ul>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="tr"><span class="model"><a target="_blank" 
          href="#"><span class="title">Product 2</span>
            <span class="one_half"><img width="300" height="300" src="" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="" srcset=""
                sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"></span><span class="one_half last_column clearfix"><span class="price">154.99 €</span></span>
            </a>
            <span class="cross_buttons">
   <a target="_blank" href="#" ><div class="button button-rezesionen buy_link">Link 1</div></a>
   <span class="extra_callout"></span>
            </span>
            </span>
            <span class="making">
        <ul>
            <li class="cleanup"><b>Attribute 1:</b>
                <span class="pro_con"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>DLorem ipsum dolor sum</span> </li>
            <li class="cleanup"><b>Attribute 2:</b>
              <span class="pro_con"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sum</span> </li>
            </ul>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="facetwp-pager"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

I would like to make only the div-table scrollable when I am on mobile.

I tried adding:

```
<div id="comparison_chart" class="faceted" style="  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;">
```

So a scrollbar should appears at the bottom of the two divs. However, it still looks like that:

[image]

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Your `overflow-x` should be `auto`, you put `overflow-x: hidden;`, this way will hide your bar at the bottom, try change it. But the best way would be use `@media` and `overflow`.

Comment: @EsdrasXavier Thx for your reply! I kindly ask you to write it out as an answer and change the example above so that I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Did it worked? And thaks for your feedback :)

Comment: Nope... didn`t work...

Comment: You want the scrool in your **X** or in your **Y**? Maybe I got it wrong :p

Comment: I would like to scroll on my X axis, so horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

use **`@media`** rule to specify any style change for mobile windows or larger windows,here the **`max-width`** property is specifies the maximum width of your mobile window.use overflow-y to provide scroll across y-axis

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body{
          overflow-y : scroll;
        }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use media queries, specify on what size you want it to be scrollable and thats it!! You can get some help to use media queries from here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Thx for your reply!